# BAT batch file to count files in a folder and then subtract 1

Tags: file, batch-file, count

I have a BAT script that counts the number of files in a folder and exports the results into a .txt. It works great, but I'm in a situation where I need to subtract 1 from the value it's currently counting. How could I alter my script to do that?

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
 PUSHD "%%G"
 FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b * ^|find /C /V ""') DO echo %%G %%H>>"..\count.txt"
 POPD
)
```

Comment: What happens if you have an empty directory, or possibly  more a directory containing only directories (of varying content)? _It is possible, and therefore the scenario should be catered for_. Do you want `-1`, `0`, or, `something else` to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to use `%%H` with the `SET /A` command to do the Arithmetic. I chose to use `%%G` as part of the `DIR` command.  This way you do not need `PUSHD` and `POPD`. I also chose to use an `IF` command to make sure the count is not zero so that it does not substract 1.

I moved the redirection of the output at the end because this opens the file for writing once instead of every time it writes a directory to the output.

The CALL command and the double percent symbols on the variable allows us to use the variable without having to enable delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
(FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b "%%G\*" 2^>NUL ^|find /C /V ""') DO (
        IF NOT "%%H"=="0" SET /A "count=%%H-1"
        CALL echo %%G %%count%%
    )
))>count.txt
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you. I changed the last line to CALL echo %%G %%count%% and it was exactly what I needed. But having the %%H in there was able to show me that math it was doing. REALLY great break down. I appreciate your explanation of everything! I learned a lot.

Comment: @KelseyCiarrocca, just a typo on my part. You will need to change the `IF` command as well.  I updated the code.